# I want to show tree level table rows using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have written code to display tree structured table, but it's not meeting my expectation. If someone help me then it would be great. It should display only row in tree structured not whole table inside table row.

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item.html">

  <tr style="width:100%">
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <i class="fa" ng-class="data.folderClass" ng-click="toggleChildren(data)"></i>  {{data.name}}
      <div id="expanded-data" ng-if="data.childrenVisible">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="nested-table">
          <div ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item.html'"></div>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        {{data.name}}
      <div id="expanded-data" ng-if="data.childrenVisible">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="nested-table">
          <div ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item.html'"></div>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</script>


<table class="table table-striped" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:30px;"><i ng-click="loadItems()" class="fa fa-refresh blueicon"></i></th>
      <th style="width:auto">Data tree</th>
      <th style="width:auto">example tree</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="data in treeData" ng-include="'tree_item.html'">

  </tbody>

</table>

</div>
```

> ------------------------------js-------------------------------

```
$scope.treeData =  [
  {
    "topic": "Node",
    "completed": "Yes",
    "date" : "2017/12/12",
    "folderClass": "fa-folder",
    "subtopics": [
      {
        "topic": "Node-1",
        "completed": "Yes",
        "date" : "2017/12/12",
        "folderClass": "fa-folder",
        "subtopics": [
            {
              "topic": "Node-1-1",
              "completed": "Yes",
              "date" : "2017/12/12",
              "folderClass": "fa-folder",
              "subtopics": []
            }, {
              "topic": "Node-1-2",
              "completed": "Yes",
              "date" : "2017/12/12",
              "folderClass": "fa-folder",
              "subtopics": []
            }
        ]
      }, 
      {
        "topic": "Node-2",
        "completed": "Yes",
        "date" : "2017/12/12",
        "folderClass": "fa-folder",
        "subtopics": [
            {
              "topic": "Node-2-1",
              "completed": "Yes",
              "date" : "2017/12/12",
              "folderClass": "fa-folder",
              "subtopics": []
            }, {
              "topic": "Node-2-2",
              "completed": "Yes",
              "date" : "2017/12/12",
              "folderClass": "fa-folder",
              "subtopics": []
            }
        ]
      }, {
        "topic": "Node-3",
        "completed": "Yes",
        "date" : "2017/12/12",
        "folderClass": "fa-folder",
        "subtopics": [
            {
              "topic": "Node-3-1",
              "completed": "Yes",
              "date" : "2017/12/12",
              "folderClass": "fa-folder",
              "subtopics": [
                {
                  "topic": "Node-3-1-1",
                  "completed": "Yes",
                  "date" : "2017/12/12",
                  "folderClass": "fa-folder",
                  "subtopics": []
                }, {
                  "topic": "Node-3-1-2",
                  "completed": "Yes",
                  "date" : "2017/12/12",
                  "folderClass": "fa-folder",
                  "subtopics": []
                }
              ]
            }, {
              "topic": "Node-3-2",
              "completed": "Yes",
              "date" : "2017/12/12",
              "folderClass": "fa-folder",
              "subtopics": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

> I want to display subtopics inside topics.
>   And the tree can be 5 level.[image: currently its showing like in the bellow picture]
>
> and result should look like showing in bellow picture.[image: result should look like picture shown bellow]

Comment: Can you add the code you tried to write yourself?

Comment: What you need to add is some control to show/hide sublevels on click

Comment: @Rick sorry i didn't included html

Comment: @Rick i have included html please do check:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating `<table>` inside `<td>`
Please take a look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/sliiice/pen/GurpF) or [this plunkr](https://next.plnkr.co/plunk/oSHU03CSGqpDvPBS)